# Create a Word file using POI

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi

My requirement is that I should read a template file and change some values in its content and write it back to another file. Most importantly it should have the same styles as that of the template.

The problem I face is that I am able to read and write, but its very difficult to transfer the styles as well. Especially I am tired trying to apply the paragraph styles to the document. Pls help me..... this is my code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
          HWPFDocument templateFile = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("D:\\POI\\testPOIin.doc"));
          HWPFDocument blankFile = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("D:\\POI\\blank.doc"));

        ParagraphProperties pp = templateFile.getRange().getParagraph(4).cloneProperties();
        blankFile.getRange().insertAfter(pp, 0);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\POI\\testPOIout.doc");
        blankFile.write(out);

      } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
          // TODO: Add catch code
          fnfe.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception ioe) {
          // TODO: Add catch code
          ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Pls let me know that I am doing wrong.....

Comment: Are you intentionally using the old binary document format, rather than the newer docx format?

Comment: Why not copy the whole file, open the copy, make changes in that and save? Should be much simpler than trying to bring over parts of the file and style...

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys...... But s I need get it done in doc is my primary requirement..... and I tried taking a copy of the entire file change the placed I needed and wrote it in a fresh file.... but I still find my alignments misplaced.... Thats Y first I want to achieve proper alignment for a single paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar task and after investigation i created solution, but it works only for docx  files:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("transformed.docx"));
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("original.docx")));
    for(XWPFParagraph p:doc.getParagraphs()){
        for(XWPFRun r:p.getRuns()){
            for(CTText ct:r.getCTR().getTList()){
                String str = ct.getStringValue();
                if(str.contains("NAME")){
                    str = str.replace("NAME", "Java Dev");
                    ct.setStringValue(str);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc.write(fos);
}
```

it operates on low level elements so it saves styles and other props. Hope it will help somebody.